# Given a working satellite, would it be possible to build a homemade transmitter/receiver?

Tags: artificial-satellite, communication, communication-satellite

Given existing low-orbit and geo-synchronous satellites, would it be possible to build a device that could send a signal to a satellite and then have that signal received on another device?  Essentially I'm wondering whether it would be possible to reverse-engineer satellite phones (without just dismantling an existing one) to send/receive signals, and if so, what would be the steps involved?  Both in terms of hardware as well as any additional steps needed (e.g. figuring out the frequency that existing satellites are listening on, any encryption/decryption that would have to happen, etc).

Comment: Relevant: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6424/what-would-one-need-to-do-in-order-to-hijack-a-satellite

Comment: Welcome to Space! This is really a question about the electronics inside satellite phones. However I think it is too broad to ask in [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/) in its current form, and there's no prior research cited. In other words, no information about what you've read or studied about satellite phones. So I wouldn't ask this there either.

Comment: About reverse-engineering of the encryption, you could have a look at existing questions in [Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions) to see if it's already been addressed.

Comment: Becca, you can very easily insert the prior research: google a little bit, and insert what you found.

Comment: @uhoh thanks for the suggestion! I wasn't quite sure what an appropriate place to post this question was, but I can add a bit more background information (always hard to tell the right level of that, too!) and repost in [Electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Paul thanks for the link – it doesn't answer all of my questions, but it definitely helps with some of them!

Comment: This would be considered off topic on Electronics SE since no specific satellite standard is identified and what remains to be asked about is a protocol security question, not an electronics one.

Answer (score 5):

As a *radio matter*, yes.  Amateur radio operators have built and contacted their own satellites, had conversations with Astronauts and Cosmonauts who were licensed Amateurs orbiting on the Shuttle, MIR, and ISS, and bounced signals off the moon, which is not only far beyond even geosynchronous orbit, but a fairly lossy reflector compared to an *active* satellite transponder.  And done all of these with home built equipment as well as commercially purchased gear.

As an *access code* matter, probably not, at least in the intent of the satellite owners.  Commercial satellites, especially those with end user terminals sold to the public are generally going to be somewhat locked down.  Someone might be able to figure out how to emulate an approved terminal like a satellite phone (especially an aging scheme where flaws might have since been discovered), but it's certainly not the *design intent* to support DIY efforts.

As a *legal* matter, almost certainly not.  Most commercial radio services are limited to `type accepted` equipment (or else that signed off on by a licensed professional technician) which excludes that home built by an individual.  Home building amateur radio gear is permitted, but as with all operations under the Amateur Radio Service, that can only be used on frequencies where amateur radio operations are permitted, which is not where commercial satellites would be.  And even if there is a case where a commercial satellite allocation and an amateur radio band share the same frequency range, such cross-service operation would not be permitted.  These rules will be fairly consistent from jurisdiction to jurisdiction, differing slightly in allowed frequencies but not in general intent.

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. My use case is a hypothetical time when government/legal restrictions have collapsed, so I am more interested in the technical ability than legality.  However, this post and others have made me think that trying to come up with some kind of communication scheme would be better served by ham radio (possibly using APRS) bounced off some kind of satellite like the ISS that's set to digipeater mode, than trying to rebuild a satellite phone.